# SharePoint Enterprise Search is not working?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

The error is "Internal server error exception"  - Even after I have given dbowner privileges to the the current admin in SQL Server, the error still shows up.

Answer (score 2):

You should look into the SharePoint logs to find more information about the issue.
At the same time I will recommend http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/ULSViewer for reading the logs.